# Publishing an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API to Azure App Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have written a simple API in ASP.NET Core 5 which is up and running on my local machine. But when I publish it to my Azure App Service, the docker container of the App Service cannot even start.

https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html

[image]

Here are the warinings and errors in my Application Logs from Azure:
[image]

What is the cause of these errors and how can I resolve them?

My gut feeling is that something is wrong with Newtonsoft.Json, although I have installed the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Newtonsoft in the web api.

Azure somehow looks for Newtonsoft Version 13.0.0 and The Newtonsoft Version in my project actually is 12.0.2.

Comment: How do you publish this application to Auzre App Services?

Comment: I published it via Visual Studio. (Release Build and then Publish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that, in my case, I have previously published a version with Newtonsoft 13.0.0.

To remove previously published files you have to check "Remove additional files at destination" in the Publish Settings. Afterwards, the error disappeared because the old Newtonsoft reference was gone.

[image]